# Is there an in-built function for the multivariate gamma distribution?

Tags: functions

[The Multivariate Gamma Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_gamma_function) <- Wikipedia link with a description of the function.

Is there an in-built function for the multivariate gamma distribution?

I found out that there used to exist a package called GAMMA done with Mathematica 4.0, but it's probably incompatible by now...

Comment: There doesn't appear to be such a built-in function.  However, taking the definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_gamma_function suggest the following should work:  `\[CapitalGamma][p_, 
  a_] := \[Pi]^(p (p - 1)/4) Product[Gamma[a + (1 - j)/2], {j, 1, p}]`.